# How to manage the full Pull Request process in Visual Studio Code with Azure DevOps

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, vscode-extensions, pull-request, review

I was trying to have a full change from the commit to the pull-request/review process in a Azure DevOps repo with Visual Studio Code.

All good till the point where I have to create a Pull Request.

I didn't find an embedded way to do it.
There is a plugin [Pull Requests for Azure Devops](https://github.com/Airizom/vscode-pull-requests-azure-devops.git) but it seems to be not maintained anymore.

Do you know any other good way to do it? Or may be Microsoft can invest in this important feature?

Comment: Hi Alex, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether the answers below can help you and feel free to comment~

Answer (score 2):

There used to be an extension, but it got pulled.

When you install the [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&) and the [devops extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops) and then [create a pull request from the terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/repos/pr?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_repos_pr_create):

```
az extension add --name azure-devops
az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/contoso project=ContosoWebApp
az devops pr create --repository MyRepo --open --source-branch branch-name
```

That last command needs 2 parameters that can be teased out of the context in a repo folder, that way you can easily alias this to a generic command.

Very few people were uring the Azure Repos and PR for Azure DevOps extensions. And most of Microsoft's investments are in GitHub.

Comment: May be I can get all the project's dependent parameter as var directly in VSC and use it. Will try.

Comment: If it works any way like the GH-cli for GitHub, it will infer the required data from the Git config as long as your Azure Devops repo is called `origin`.

Answer (score 2):

In our team, we started using the Azure CLI but found it too verbose to be practical. We also wanted to have a similar API to the GitHub CLI.

To fix this, we developed [doing-cli](https://ing-bank.github.io/doing-cli/), which is essentially a wrapper around the Azure CLI with a feel of the GitHub CLI.

A typical workflow for us is:

- `doing list` to see open work items
- `doing issue create <issue title>` to create a new work item
- `doing pr create <issue number>` to create a branch and a PR based on an existing work item

Our company requires that all PRs are linked to a work item. But sometimes you want to fix things quickly, without having to always create a new work item, create a new branch, link them and open a PR. So we implemented `doing workon <title>` which will do all these steps for you, as well as checkout the newly created branch.

Comment: Like the idea.. but seems broken. I get 404's for list and pr create..

Comment: @RBenR Have you tried following the [connection problems page](https://ing-bank.github.io/doing-cli/howto/connection_problems/#working-behind-a-corporate-proxy-virtual-private-network-vpn)?

Comment: I eventually got it working - I had to tweak some URL that it was not liking I believe during the setup. Regardless even after that it still didn't seem to work right so I gave up on it after that. It created some new branch on my repo instead of just creating a normal PR for my existing branch.

I have no idea what workflow that it was trying to do tbh. It's not how I or any dev I work w/ work though.

Comment: I do see now that the pr create explanation above says it will create a new branch and then a PR for the existing work. The point of PR's imho is that you create it for the existing branch - then you either keep working it while people review it w/ minor changes based on input or issues you find after you think it is solid or create a new branch if you need to not disturb that PR.

Only time I reject my own PRs is if there was some major changes/rewrite that needs to happen.

Comment: @RBenR I see what you mean. I think we can clarify the documentation.
The idea for this package is that the azDo setup in our company requires all PRs to be linked to a work item. In addition, very often our work starts from an existing work item that was created during planning. 
The idea is therefore that `doing pr create <work item ID>` starts from a work item, creates a branch and also a PR linked to the correct work item. This is a requirement for the PR to be merged.
I'll try to clarify the docs. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yea, that seems sorta backwards to me - when I have a ticket ID I create a new branch w/ that ID and small description from the start. It doesn't get that stuff created at the end and just before the PR is made.

I guess it might make sense to create it at the end if the person dev'ing a ticket may change.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jessehouwing's answer, you can create pull requests using Azure CLI.

In addition, you can also use the REST API [Pull Requests - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=6.0
```

Here is an example of the request body:

```
{
  "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/npaulk/my_work",
  "targetRefName": "refs/heads/new_feature",
  "title": "A new feature",
  "description": "Adding a new feature"
}
```

Comment: Hi Jane, yes this is good but not really usable unless developing something around it. I was searching for something that would allow me manage everything inside VSC.